# How to know if actionscript 1, actionscript 2, or actionscript 3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, actionscript-2

I don't have a specific code sample, but is there a general way to guess what version of Actionscript the code snippet is: 1 or 2 or 3?

I read somewhere that if it's code in the timeline, it's considered Actionscript 1.

Answer (score 7):

Update: My experience with AS1/2 is limited and this is based on what I've seen in AS forums. From the comments it seems that the second and third methods of event handling are valid in both AS1 and AS2.

The syntax of handling events are different:

ActionScript 3

```
addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, handleClick);
private function handleClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{
  //Just do it
}
```

ActionScript 2

```
onRelease = function():Void{ //it's not void - it's Void
  //do something
}
```

ActionScript 1

```
on(release){
  //do something
}
```

You might find this page helpful: [Migrating from AS2 to AS3](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/migration.html)

AS3 way of adding a new children is `new` followed by `addChild`

```
var s:Sprite = new Sprite();
var tf:TextField = new TextField();
this.addChild(s);
s.addChild(tf);
```

It used to be `createMovieClip` and `createTextField` methods earlier - not sure about exact version though.

```
_root.createTextField("mytext",1,100,100,300,100);
//that is name, depth, x, y, width, height
mytext.multiline = true;
mytext.wordWrap = true;
mytext.border = false;
```

Earlier, if you had the `name` property of a child, you could access the child from the parent using `parent.childName` even if the parent class didn't have a property called `childName`. With AS3, it is possible only if the parent class have a property called `childName` (of appropriate type) and you have assigned the child's reference to it (or you have created that property on the dynamic class `MovieClip`). There is `getChildByName()` - but it will return the first child with the given name (and it is possible to have duplicate names in a child list).

Comment: actually your 2nd and 3rd snippets are valid in both AS1 and AS2.

Comment: I don't believe the AS2 snippet is valid in AS1, but the AS1 snippet is valid in AS2.  However, I don't have any way of actually testing that.

Comment: onRelease = function()... was perfectly valid in Flash 6, and AS2 was introduced in Flash 7 ;)

Comment: Thanks for the correction. My exp with AS1/2 is limited - added a fine print to the post.

Comment: the ":Void" (data typing) was AS2-only though ^^

Answer (score 2):

Between AS3 and AS1/2 there are a lot of differences and in most cases you will see it right away (look for addChild and addEventListener in AS3).
The differences between AS1 and AS2 however where far less obvious, but probably the most relevant language-wise is the introduction of the "class" concept together with a few statements and keywords for OOP development (class, public, private, etc...).

EDIT: look, the wikipedia explains it much better:

> 2003–2006: ActionScript 2.0 The next
>   major revision of the language,
>   ActionScript 2.0, was introduced in
>   September 2003 with the release of
>   Flash MX 2004 and its corresponding
>   player, Flash Player 7. In response to
>   user demand for a language better
>   equipped for larger and more complex
>   applications, ActionScript 2.0
>   featured compile-time type checking
>   and class-based syntax, such as the
>   keywords class and extends. (While
>   this allowed for a more structured
>   object-oriented programming approach,
>   the code would still be compiled to
>   ActionScript 1.0 bytecode, allowing it
>   to be used on the preceding Flash
>   Player 6 as well. In other words, the
>   class-based inheritance syntax was a
>   layer on top of the existing
>   prototype-based system.) With
>   ActionScript 2.0, developers could
>   constrain variables to a specific type
>   by adding a type annotation so that
>   type mismatch errors could be found at
>   compile-time. ActionScript 2.0 also
>   introduced class-based inheritance
>   syntax so that developers could create
>   classes and interfaces, much as they
>   would in class-based languages such as
>   Java and C++. This version conformed
>   partially to the ECMAScript Fourth
>   Edition draft specification.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActionScript#ActionScript_2.0

Answer (score 0):

Well, it doesn't only have to be ActionScript 1 that has code in the the timeline. But a easy and quick way to check out what version you are coding in, is just to click a frame (empty or not) and press F9. It will say on the left hand side what version it is (I am pretty sure..) :)